# How to show a default preview icon in case if it's not possible to create a thumbnail?

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I am setting up Jquery-File-Upload for my website. The script is you can see here:

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/‎

This script automatically creates preview thumbnails of image files, however, it allows to select any files (doc, pdf etc). If user selects such a file, the script shows error "File type not allowed" but doesn't show any thumbnail. I want to set up a default thumbnail image for all non-image files.

I modified jquery.fileupload-image.js file:

**Original:**

```
setImage:function(data,options){
if(data.preview&&!options.disabled){
data.files[data.index][options.name||'preview']=data.preview;
}
return data;
}
```

**My modification:**

```
setImage:function(data,options){
if(data.preview&&!options.disabled){
data.files[data.index][options.name||'preview']=data.preview;
} else {
data.files[data.index][options.name||'preview']='<img src="/images/default-thumbnail.png">';
}
return data;
}
```

It works perfectly but the problem is that I will use this script in different sections of my website and thumbnail size always will be different.

So, I need to define default thumbnail in my html file. I tried:

```
var defaultthumbnail = '<img src="/images/default-thumbnail.png">';
```

or in options:

```
defaultthumbnail: '<img src="/images/default-thumbnail.png">'
```

but it doesn't work. The script doesn't return image and doesn't show any error.

Any ideas?

```
<script>
$(function () {
var formData = $('#fileupload').serializeArray();
var defaultthumbnail = '<img src="/images/default-thumbnail.png">';

'use strict';
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
url:'//mydomain.com'
});

$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
autoUpload:false,
maxNumberOfFiles:10,
disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
.test(window.navigator.userAgent)
});
if ($.support.cors) {
$.ajax({
url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
type: 'HEAD'
}).fail(function () {
$('<div class="alert alert-danger"/>')
.text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
new Date())
.appendTo('#fileupload');
});
} 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks that Jquery-File-Upload project is abandoned...

So if you want to show a default thumbnail for unsupported file types, do the following:

```
<script>
var defaultthumbnail = '<img src="/images/default-thumbnail.png" />';
$(function () {
var formData = $('#fileupload').serializeArray();
'use strict';
..............
..............
</script>
```

in jquery.fileupload-image.js file

change

```
setImage:function(data,options){
if(data.preview&&!options.disabled){
data.files[data.index][options.name||'preview']=data.preview;
}
return data;
}
```

to

```
setImage:function(data,options){
if(data.preview&&!options.disabled){
data.files[data.index][options.name||'preview']=data.preview;
} else {
data.files[data.index][options.name||'preview']=defaultthumbnail;
}
return data;
}
```

Comment: Don't know that it's abandoned, there was an update a few months ago. Thanks for this, had the same issue and this cleared things up.